# Puppeteer: Wait for frame detached event

Tags: node.js, dom, puppeteer, frame

Using puppeteer, I’m wondering how I can wait for (with a timeout) a frame to become detached. I know there’s `frame.isDetached()` but this only checks instantaneously. I want to wait a bit to see if the frame does become detached when the webpage reloads (if it doesn’t then I know that I’m still stuck on the same page). Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show a minimal example of the use case/page behavior and your code so far? You might want to try a busy loop or `page.waitForFunction` to poll on an arbitrary condition -- I don't think there's a direct builtin alternative for this, i.e. `frame.waitForDetached()`.

Comment: There is, it's `page.onFrameDetached`

Comment: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#event-framedetached